# 'There are no forms to display' message in Sitecore 9 Forms Dashboard

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, sitecore-forms

I am getting 'There are no forms to display' message in Sitecore 9 Forms Dashboard in Production environment

[image]

In chrome developer tools, getting below error message in Console tab with below error message on clicking 403 item

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","exceptionType":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","stackTrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild indexes?

Comment: Try logging out and in again.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of options how to solve this issues.

### 1. Not touching your Sitecore installation.

1a. You need to use Firefox instead as there was a change in one of past versions of Chrome on how it handles XHR headers which is causing trouble.

1b. Downgrade Chrome

### 2. Touching your Sitecore installation.

2a. Other options are upgrading to Sitecore 9.1 - where this issue is definetely solved

2b. Or possibly waiting for Sitecore 9.0 Update 3 - where this issue might be solved

For further details take a look on my blog post with similar error in Marketing Automation: https://tothecore.sk/2018/03/22/marketing-automation-not-working-in-sitecore-9-update-1-with-chrome-64/

Comment: Thanks for the update Peter. I have tried in firefox as well as Chrome but no luck.

Comment: I am trying to get reports of each form. Is there any other way we can export the data to CSV apart from downloading from Forms Dashboard (using powershell)?

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to control panel -> Indexing manager and rebuild indexes.

It is an existing bug in sitecore 9, rebuilding master and web indexes through indexing manager resolves the issue

Comment: How about some context as to why?